# Sample array at even intervals

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that could be any size and I'm interested in a fixed number of elements, but evenly distributed.  So say I want 1000 elements.  If there are 1000 or less elements in the array, I want them all, so that's easy.  If there were 2000 elements in the array, I would want every second one.  3000 elements and I'd want every third one... and so on.

I'm having trouble implementing this.  I thought of using modulo and this works for round numbers.  e.g. 2000 / 1000 = 2 so a simple `if (n % 2 == 0)` works here (so skip each element where it evaluates true).  Likewise for 1200: the excess is 200 so 1200 / 200 = 6 so `if (n % 6 == 0)` also works.

However, it breaks down when the number of elements divided by the excess isn't a nice round number:

> elements = 2788
>   limit = 1000
>   factor = 2788 / (2788 - 1000) = 1.559288

Here the modulo operator won't work as `n % 1.55928` is never going to give a remainder of zero.  Does anyone know how to achieve this?  I'm using JavaScript.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your example for 1200 elements. `n % 6 == 0` would select only 200 of them, not 1000?

Comment: Sorry, my dodgy explanation at fault, should be n % 6 != 0, which would select 1000 and omit 200.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a uniform discrete distribution. Because the number of elements is not divisible by the limit, you would want some flexibility in the limit to keep it evenly distributed. To do so, you could just perform the sampling in elements/limit intervals, rounding the result to its nearest integer.

If your limit is flexible and you can cover more ground by finding the biggest possible limit (in this case, 697).